# mysql reporting, analytics query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create `mysql` query to count me some data, without where clause, not like:

```
select count(Gender),concat(Gender), Year from sometable where Year = 2015 group by Gender
union
select count(Gender),concat(Gender), Year from sometable where Year = 2016 group by Gender;
```

but more like:

```
select Gender,Year something to count ....
```

here is example:

in table i have

```
---------------
Gender | Year
---------------
Male     2016
Male     2015
Female   2015
Female   2016
---------------
```

end result to be

```
          ---------------
           2015 | 2016
          ---------------
Male        1       1
Female      1       1
          ---------------
```

Comment: Would `select gender, year, count(*) from table group by gender, year` suffice?

Comment: Seems like the post is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns.Creating columns dynamically from row values is a problem.I have given one temporary solution.Check if it would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume the table name as `gender_count`.To get the result like you wanted try the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    gender,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            gender_count
        WHERE
            year = '2015' AND gender = gc.gender) '2015',
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            gender_count
        WHERE
            year = '2016' AND gender = gc.gender) '2016'
FROM
    gender_count gc
```

Comment: What about years before 2015 and after 2016?

Comment: Yeah I know that would not be possible,the OP asked for it,that is why given this solution.Let us wait for the OP's opinion.Constructing columns dynamically I think would be some problem.